# POST to multiple tables in Asp.Net Web Api

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

In the Asp.Net Web Api of my Xamarin forms mobile application I have two tables
**Order** & **OrderDetails** the fields are as below.

```
Order
---------
Id
CustomerID
TotalAmount
Order Status 

OrderDetails
------------
Id
ItemId
ItemName
ItemRate
Order_Id
```

On the button click, I want to post data to both tables simultaneously.
The order table will contain only one row and the OrderDetails table may contain more than one row.

When we create the controller for the two models it will only generate code for CURD operation for separately for the two models. But i want to post data simultaneously to both tables.

Please help me with the POST/PUT code as required to use in Asp.net Web Api controller to perform this

Comment: you need to create an Order model that includes all the necessary data, and post that model to your controller.  The controller is then responsible for saving the data in tables.

Comment: As Jason said you will just need to send the command properly to your controller and it will handle the rest, that said, I don't see a relationship between Order and OrderDetails